# There is an error running the todos-with-undo project

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

An error occurred when I ran the todos-with-undo project on the redux documentation page

todo with undo - example crush both locally and on the sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-with-undo

also, appear in this page broken
https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples#todos-with-undo

'past' and 'future' do not exist when the program starts running.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
src/containers/UndoRedo.js:19
  16 | const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  17 |   console.log(state);
  18 |   return ({
> 19 |   canUndo: state.todos.past.length > 0,
  20 |   canRedo: state.todos.future.length > 0
  21 | })}
  22 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bug happens in the sandbox and locally also.

I open a pull request for fixing it , and open an issue

pull request
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/3423

issue
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3422

if you want to use this example you could use my branch